# How do I handle laravel API access token in Nextjs

Tags: laravel, next.js, token, server-side-rendering

Background:
I have a laravel API to retrieve data from database. I use laravel passport to protect my API. The access_token is required when I call the API to retrieve data. The access_token can be obtained by calling ./oauth/token with the client secret provided by laravel passport.

I have a Nextjs web to call the API. I decided to store the client secret on the Nextjs project by .env.local. When I need to call API, I check whether the token exist or not. If the token is not exist, I would call ./oauth/token with the client secret to get a new token.

Questions here:

Is that the flow to obtain token correct? Any best practice?

How do I save the token to allow both server side function/component and client side component to access the token?